# Are Minkowski sums of upward closed "convex" sets in $\mathbb{N}^k$ still "convex"? (WAS: Comparing mana costs in Magic: The Gathering)

Tags: co.combinatorics, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, polyhedra, lattice-polytopes

This was originally a question about comparing mana costs in Magic: The Gathering, but it's turned into a question about Minkowski sums of upward-closed convex sets in $\mathbb{N}^k$.  The original question is preserved below, if you want to see the original motivation (or have an answer to the original question that doesn't bear on this new one).

The question is this -- say we have two convex polyhedra $A$ and $B$ in $\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}^k$ whose vertices lie in the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^k$ (they're "lattice polyhedra"); and say moreover that both $A$ and $B$ are upward closed in the obvious partial order (i.e., for each of them, the recession cone is equal to $\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}^k$).  Then is $(A+B)\cap \mathbb{Z}^k=(A\cap\mathbb{Z}^k)+(B\cap\mathbb{Z}^k)$?

This question seems to be more commonly asked in the case that $A$ and $B$ are *polytopes*, that is bounded, that is both have recession cone equal to $\{0\}$ rather than to $\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}^k$.  In this case the answer is no, and just proving conditions under which it holds is as best I can tell an open problem in dimensions greater than 2.  But I'm wondering if in this alternate context the problem is easier.

That's the question; but if you want to know what this has to do with mana costs in Magic: The Gathering, or whether it might be easier to answer the original question rather than this, read on...

---

Yes, this is a combinatorics question, dealing with something like matchings where sometimes one vertex is allowed to match two other vertices instead of just one like usual!  But it arises from Magic and so will need some setup to state.  (I would certainly be interested in generalizations, too.)

Background: In Magic: The Gathering, there are 6 types of "mana", denoted {W}, {U}, {B}, {R}, {G} (the 5 colors of mana), and {C} (colorless mana).  (We can also imagine a 7th type, {P}, representing 2 life; this is not an actual type of mana.)  Mana comes in whole number amounts; by an "amount of mana" I mean a specified whole number amount of each type (and some amount of life, I suppose).  A *mana cost* describes a set of amounts of mana sufficient to pay the cost.  A mana cost consists of some number of the following symbols:

- {W}, {U}, {B}, {R}, {G} -- payable only by 1 mana of that color
- {C} -- payable only by 1 colorless mana
- {W/U}, {U/B}, {B/R}, {R/G}, {G/W}, {W/B}, {U/R}, {B/G}, {R/W}, {G/U} -- payable by 1 mana of either appropriate color (all 10 color pairs are listed here)
- {1} -- payable by 1 mana of any type, colored or colorless
- {W/P}, {U/P}, {B/P}, {R/P}, {G/P} -- payable by the appropriate color or by 2 life (which we can think of as a fictitious type of mana, {P})
- {2/W}, {2/U}, {2/B}, {2/R}, {2/G} -- payable by the appropriate color of mana or by any 2 mana (colored or colorless)

(Yes, for those familiar with Magic, I am ignoring {X} and I am ignoring the question of snow, since those don't seriously affect the problem.  Indeed we didn't actually need all the above, but I figured I'd be thorough...)

We can put a partial ordering on the set of mana costs as follows: A≤B if any amount of mana sufficient to pay for B is sufficient to pay for A.

Then, the question is, given two mana costs, how can we determine whether one is less than equal to another or not?

If we ignore the existence of the symbols of the form {2/M}, then this problem is not hard; using Hall's marriage theorem, we can see that one just has to check a number of inequalities; specifically, that for each set S of types of mana (including the fictitious {P}), the number of mana symbols in A corresponding to a subset of S must be no more than the number of mana symbols in B corresponding to a subset of S.  This gives us at most 2^7 inequalities to check (in fact given the symbols that actually exist one only needs to check 65 of them).

But the {2/M} symbols are more of a problem.  Because they can correspond to 1 or 2 mana, the marriage theorem doesn't apply.  One way to handle this is disambiguation -- each {2/M} symbol can be disambiguated to either {2} or {M}.  Then A≤B iff for every disambiguation B' of B there's some disambiguation A' of A such that A'≤B'.

However, this is slow in the worst case, because it requires checking lots of disambiguations.  My question is: Can we do better?

I hypothesize the following two statements that will help reduce the number of disambiguations needed when symbols of the form {2/M} are involved:

1. Cancellation applies.  That is: If we define addition of mana costs in the obvious way, it's clear that $a\le b$ implies $a+c\le b+c$.  If we don't allow symbols of the form {2/M}, the converse also holds, by the reasoning above.  Question: Does it also hold when such symbols are allowed?  **Edit**: It seems a positive answer to #3 implies a positive answer to this (see comments).  I'm retitling the question to focus on #3.
2. Suppose we have mana costs A and B and suppose M is a color such that the symbol {2/M} does not occur in A.  Is it true then that A≤B if and only if A≤B', where B' consists of B but with all instances of {2/M} replaced by {1}? (**EDIT**: Disproved in the comments by Pace Nielsen.  It does however hold if we require A have no symbols of the form {2/M} for *all* colors M (again, sketch in the comments), but unfortunately that weaker form doesn't form such a useful part of computing the order relation.)
3. (**Added** after Will Sawin asked it in the comments) -- is the set of amounts of mana sufficient to pay for a given mana cost (including the fictitious {P}) equal to a convex polyhedron intersected with the integer lattice?  (Or integer amounts of mana and even amounts of life, if you prefer to think of it that way.)  If so this might give us a faster way to compare than disambiguation, by comparing the convex sets (assuming they can be determined quickly; I'm not sure that they can).  (This is definitely true if we ignore symbols of the form {2/M}, by the above reasoning.)  Note that it's important here that we allow overpaying; it's not true if we don't (see comments).

(I don't think there's any way to get rid of the necessity of doing at least *some* disambiguations; if A has more of some {2/M} symbol than B, I think you are just going to have to handle those manually.  But both the above statements at least would bring it down to only doing that.)

So far I haven't been able to prove these work, nor find any counterexample.  Can anyone prove or disprove these?

In addition like I said I'd be interested to see generalizations.  As long as each symbol corresponds to 1 mana the whole thing just comes down to the marriage theorem like I said above.  But when symbols can correspond to varying amounts I wouldn't expect it to work so nicely in general.  It does seem to still work nicely for the set of symbols that actually exist, as listed above (although I might be wrong!).  Is there some abstract property of this set of symbols that causes this, so that we can say when this sort of thing happens?  It would be interesting to see.

Thank you all!

Comment: In "*Then, the question is, given two mana costs, how can we determine whether one is equal to another or not?*", should it be "*...less than or equal to...*"? That seems to make more sense of the following paragraph. (PS You also conveniently omitted half-integral mana costs).

Comment: I must be misunderstanding something, because the easiest example seems to be a counterexample. Consider $A_1=\{2/W\}$ and $B=\{W\}$. Then $A_1 < B$ with inequality. But the given algorithm would translate $A_1$ to $A_2 = \{1\}\{W\}$, and $B < A_2$, again with inequality.

Comment: You are absolutely right!  Wow, I didn't think that through.  (I was so focused on the question of whether cancellation was OK that I failed to actually investigate the second part.)  OK.  I'll take that part out and restrict to a narrower question I also wanted to ask.  (Also, thanks for the correction regarding the initial "less than or equal to".)  (And yes I omitted half-integers; they don't fundamentally change the question (just double everything) and they only exist on Un-cards anyway.)

Comment: Are (2/M)'s payable with any two mana, or with any two of the same color?

Comment: If we allow more general symbols then cancellation might not hold. For example, if $\{3/BB\}$ can either be paid with $\{B\}\{B\}$ or with any three mana, then $\{B/W\}\{B\}\{W\}\{3\} \geq \{B/W\}\{3/BB\}\{3/WW\}$ but $\{B\}\{W\}\{3\} \not\geq\{3/BB\}\{3/WW\}$.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer Any two mana.  (But not life.)

Comment: OK, I see now how I made such a dumb mistake -- I got confused by the reverse.  I forgot that in $A\le B$, the role of A and B with regard to disambiguations is not symmetric.  As such, #2 *does* make sense for B, but not for A.  I'm going to re-edit the question to put that bit back in (and rephrase that whole section.)

Comment: Your new question #2 is still negative.  Take $\{2/B\}\{W\}\geq \{2/W\}\{W/B\}$.  If we replace $\{2/B\}$ with $\{1\}$, then the inequality breaks.

Comment: Nice!  Didn't manage to come up with that one.  I think the more restricted form where we require A have no symbols of the form {2/M} for any color might still hold.  But that's substantially less useful.  I think I didn't manage to come up with your example because I was so focused on that case and didn't quite realize how much a difference other 2-brid symbols could make.

Comment: Your new narrower question #2 has a positive answer.  Sketch: Take B=B'+{2/M}.  Working by contradiction, let x be a payment for B'+{1} that doesn't pay for A.  First check that x must pay for all {C} costs in A.  Next, since x plus a colorless pays for B, it pays for A.  But that extra colorless can only be spent on {1}.  Thus A=A'+{1}.  A quick argument shows that x pays for A', and has no unused mana left over (& if there is unspent life, it can't be spent). But now, counting mana and spendable life, we see that there is a payment for B'+{M} which simply cannot pay for A.

Comment: Are the sets of vectors of quantities of mana that can pay for a given mana cost equal to the intersection of a convex body (with integer vertices) with the integer lattice? If so that would give an algorithm, by comparing these convex bodies.

Comment: Pace Nielsen: Hah, I came up with more or less the same proof just a bit ago, because I hadn't checked this today and so hadn't seen yours!  Will go edit that in...

Comment: Julian Rosen: Huh, your example is particularly interesting because the symbol being cancelled is {W/B}.  I.e. it's not just that general symbols can't be cancelled but that they break cancellation more generally.  Although at least the 6 only-one-way-to-pay-these symbols can obviously be cancelled no matter what...

Comment: An arguably simpler example than @Julian's, in the sense that it drops out of an attempted proof, is $BW(B+W) \ge (BB+WW)(B+W)$ but $BW \not\ge BB+WW$. Note the advantages of sum-product notation for seeing why.

Comment: @WillSawin: Good idea, seems likely.  Obviously not true if we allow generalized symbols that don't exist.  Definitely true if omit 2-brids.  With 2-brids?  Seems likely, not sure at the moment how to prove it. The fact that we're allowing for overpaying for at least that amount will be necessary here if so.  E.g. {2/W}{2/U}, could be paid with WWB or UUB, average is WUB, which works but only because we're allowing overpaying.

Comment: Harry, are you trying to make an argument that they should bring back mana burn?  ;-)

Comment: OK, progress: I'm pretty sure a positive answer to #3 implies a positive answer to #1. (I'm *not* sure a positive answer to #3 implies a fast algorithm as stated above, because how do you quickly get a representation of the polyhedra involved?)  Here's why: There's a theorem that (ordered) cancellation holds for Minkowski sums of closed, bounded, nonempty convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$. From this one gets that the same holds if replace "bounded" by "have same cone of directions". So question then is, do Minkowski sum and intersection w/lattice commute? In general no, but maybe for upclosed yes?

Comment: To be clear that's upward closed in $\mathbb{N}^n$, so that the cone of directions (I forget the proper term) is exactly $\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}^n$.  I suspect this may be an open problem.  But I'm going to edit the question anyway (and I think retitle it with this more mathematical focus!)

Comment: Er, I seem to have left out the last part of the argument there, but the point is that if Minkowski sum and intersection with the lattice commute then one can take the cancellation argument from $\mathbb{R}^k$ and transfer it to these sets here in $\mathbb{N}^k$.

Comment: Since I haven't had time to work on my partial answer, I'll throw open one idea in case it unblocks something for someone else: with the sum-product notation I used above ($+$ for the alternation of {W/B} etc. and $\cdot$ or simple concatenation to combine costs which must both be paid), we *almost* have a commutative idempotent semiring. We're just lacking an additive identity, which would have to be an unpayable cost and would be the greatest element in the partial order and a multiplicative annihilator. Might a tropical geometer have something useful to say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that all of the standard counter-examples to the polytope question easily adapt to be counter examples to this question: Take any polytopes in $\mathbb{Z}^{k-1}$ with $(A_0+B_0) \cap \mathbb{Z}^{k-1} \neq (A_0 \cap \mathbb{Z}^{k-1}) + (B_0 \cap \mathbb{Z}^{k-1})$. Embed $\mathbb{Z}^{k-1}$ into $\mathbb{Z}^k$ as $\{ (x_1, \ldots, x_k) : \sum x_i=0 \}$. Let $A$ and $B$ be the Minkowski sums $A_0+\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^k$ and $B_0 + \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^k$. Then $(A+B) \cap \mathbb{Z}^{k-1} = (A_0+B_0) \cap \mathbb{Z}^{k-1}$, $A \cap \mathbb{Z}^{k-1}=A_0\cap \mathbb{Z}^{k-1}$ and $B \cap \mathbb{Z}^{k-1}=B_0\cap \mathbb{Z}^{k-1}$, so $A$ and $B$ have the same problem.

As a concrete example, take $A_0 = \mathrm{Hull}( (0,0,0),\ (1,1,-2))$ and $B_0 = \mathrm{Hull}( (1,0,-1),\ (0,1,-1))$. Then $(1,1,-2) \in A_0 + B_0$, but is not in $(A_0 \cap \mathbb{Z}^3) + (B_0 \cap \mathbb{Z}^3)$. Take $A = A_0 + \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^3$ and $B = B_0 + \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^3$ and you see exactly the same problem occurring with the recession cones your requested.

Comment: I suppose this can be adapted to any recession cone...?

Comment: Oh, that's a good point (and makes some sense of why I failed to find counterexamples...). I have to note that this doesn't satisfy the condition I specified that $A$ and $B$ themselves be contained in the first orthant but that's easily fixed (translate them up until they are and it still works).

Comment: Annoyingly, this answers the revised question but not the original. That is, we know that "cost convexity" implies cancellation, and I asked whether "symbol convexity" (which holds for MTG symbols) implies "cost convexity". The answer is no. Unfortunately that doesn't tell us whether cost convexity does indeed hold! It still might hold even though the implication doesn't work. Still, unless someone posts a solution to that pretty quickly, I think I'm going to call this solved, even though the original question remains unsolved. And then if someone wants to re-ask that or something they can...

Comment: I suppose this is the best we can do for now, though -- your answer shows that to solve this problem, we'd have to solve the problem for polytopes in one dimension less.  And even proving sufficient conditions it's not know how to do in dimensions greater than 2.  So since there are more than 3 types of mana, this is probably the best answer we'll get for now.  I'm going to mark this solved.